# An excecise of the Fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: integration

This excercise says:

Find the derivative $\frac{dy}{dx}$ of the following implicit function:

$\int_{0}^{y}e^{-t^2} dt +\int_{0}^{x^2}sin^{2}(t) dt=0$

Well, it appear to be really simple the first time I approached it: appliying the Fundamental theorem of calculus, but turns out that I really don't understanding it completely. Using the theorem I get:

$F'(x)=e^{-y^2}$, $G'(x)=2xsin^2(x^2)$

And getting to this point:

$e^{-y^2}+2xsin^2(x^2)=0$

But here is where I don't understand. I have the two finctions, but they are the derivative of the initial integral. Do I need to apply the derivative again to get o what the excercise is requesting, or is it enough until this point?

Comment: You mean: $F(y) = \int_0^y e^{-t^2}dt$ and $F'(y) = e^{-y^2}$. No $x$ to be seen there.

Answer (score 2):

By Chain Rule the derivative of the first term is $e^{-y^{2}} \frac {dy} {dx}$. Rest should be clear from this.

Comment: Shoudn't it have a $-2y$?

Comment: No. $\int_0^{y} e^{-t^{2}} dt= \phi (y)$ where $\phi (x)=\int_0^{x} e^{-t^{2}} dt$. So the derivative is $\phi '(y) y'$.

Comment: Oh, right. Thank you very much I didn't see it.

Answer (score 1):

If $$F(y) = \int_0^y e^{-t^2} dt $$ then $$ \frac{d F(y)}{dy}  = e^{-y^2}$$
which means that, by the chain rule: $$ \frac{d F(y(x))}{dx}  = \left.\frac{d F(y)}{dy} \right|_{y=y(x)} \cdot  \frac{d y(x)}{dx} = e^{-y(x)^2}\frac{d y(x)}{dx}$$
Therefore the equation on $y(x)$ that you should have gotten is $$ e^{-y(x)^2} \frac{d y(x)}{dx} + 2x \sin(x^2) = 0$$